# Error starting datanode on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, docker

I'm trying to run a hadoop cluster via Docker. I have one virtual machine as the namenode and another for the datanode, but the datanode gives me this error running `start-dfs.sh`:

```
namenode: namenode running as process 130. Stop it first.
```

The command jps on the datanode does not show the namenode running. Then I try to start it by hand, using:

```
hadoop namenode
```

And it fails with this error:

```
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to [namenode:9000] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
```

So far it seems that namenode is not accesible or is not listening on port 9000. But the network setup is correct: if I execute on datanode:

```
telnet namenode 9000
```

It correctly connects to the namenode, and the command `netstat -apn | grep 9000` from namenode shows the incoming connection. If I shut down dfs on namenode (`stop-dfs.sh`), the telnet command from datanode fails with "`Connection closed by foreign host.`"

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value> <!-- I have tried with 1 and 2 too -->
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
      <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://namenode:9000</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>
```

Thanks!

Comment: check with `ps -u $USER` what is pid `130`, if there is something kill it using `kill -9 130`

Comment: @Vishrant I did it and I don't have any process with pid 130. I'm root. Thanks!